# How to authenticate Supertest requests with Passport /Facebook strategy/?

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, passport.js, supertest

I'm using Passport.js for authentication (Facebook strategy) and testing with Mocha and Supertest. How can I create a session and make authenticated requests with Supertest for Facebook strategy?

Here is the example test for when user not logged in:

```
  describe 'when user not logged in', ->

    describe 'POST /api/posts', ->
      it 'respond with 401', (done)->
        request(app).
          post(API.url('posts')).
          set('Accept', 'application/json').
          send(post: data).
          expect('Content-Type', /json/).
          expect(401, done)
```

Thank you for advice :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are few different things here it looks like, so I've divided my answer into two parts.

1) You first must create test users through the Facebook.  You can do so via one of two methods, 1) Facebook's Graph API, or 2) Through the Roles page of your application.

2) The recommend method for persisting sessions with SuperTest is using a SuperAgent method called .agent() to persist sessions.  Anything you can do with SuperAgent, you can do with SuperTest.  See this [Github](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/26) post for more.

```
var supertest = require('supertest');
var app = require('../lib/your_app_location');

describe('when user not logged in', function() {
    describe('POST /api/posts', function() {
        var agent1 = supertest.agent(app);

        agent1
            .post(API.url('posts'))
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .send(post: data)
            .(end(function(err, res) {
                should.not.exist(err);
                res.should.have.status(401);
                should.exist(res.headers['set-cookie']);
                done();
            }));
    });
});
```

There are some other good code snippets on the VisionMedia Github.  Please find them [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/test/node/agency.js).

Comment: Can you show an example of how you authenticate with facebook? i.e how you carry out the login? I feel like I'm maybe missing something.

Answer (score 2):

The general solution is to create a cookie jar that will be re-used between requests.

The following example isn't passport specific, but should work:

```
var request = require('request');

describe('POST /api/posts', function () {
    // Create a new cookie jar
    var j = request.jar();
    var requestWithCookie = request.defaults({jar: j}),

    // Authenticate, thus setting the cookie in the cookie jar
    before(function(done) {
        requestWithCookie.post('http://localhost/user', {user: 'foo', password: 'bar'}, done);
    });

    it('should get the user profile', function (done) {
        requestWithCookie.get('http://localhost/user', function (err, res, user) {
            assert.equal(user.login, 'foo');
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this solution for the Local Strategy? or Basic authentication?

Answer (score 0):

This [example](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/test/node/agency.js) shows how to do the SuperTest part of the testing:

```
describe('request', function() {
  describe('persistent agent', function() {
    var agent1 = request.agent();
    var agent2 = request.agent();
    var agent3 = request.agent();
    var agent4 = request.agent();

    it('should gain a session on POST', function(done) {
      agent3
        .post('http://localhost:4000/signin')
        .end(function(err, res) {
          should.not.exist(err);
          res.should.have.status(200);
          should.not.exist(res.headers['set-cookie']);
          res.text.should.include('dashboard');
          done();
        });
    });
```

Here's a [blog post](http://jaketrent.com/post/authenticated-supertest-tests/) about it.